# When I apply a CSS class, the class is applied but with an empty class

Tags: html, css

In the `head` of my HTML document I have all of my CCS custom classes in a `style` tag like this:

```
.purple-topbordered {
  border-top-color: #9c27b0;
}
.red-topbordered {
  border-top-color: #f44336;
}
.screenCentered {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}​
.editableInput {
  color: #2196f3;
}
```

When I do, for example:

```
<div class="red-topbordered"></div>
```

the CCS class applies correctly but when I try to use the *editableInput* class on a:

```
<i class="fas fa-clock"></i>
```

to look like this:

```
<i class="fas fa-clock editableInput"></i>
```

When I go to the Chrome Dev tools I see that the class is applied to the `i` tag but no color style is defined.

Can someone point out what the problem could be? This never happen to me before.

Comment: `color` is the text color. Your `<i>` tag is empty, no text = no visible color.

Comment: Please click the `<>` and create a [mcve]

Comment: Hi if any below answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: thanks for the reply... I will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your css has a invalid character. There is a red dot in your css at the end of `.screenCentered` css.

[image]

Replace your css with below one.

And also as I can see you are using `font-awesome` library...`fas fa-clock` should be `fa fa-clock-o`

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.purple-topbordered{
  border-top-color: #9c27b0;
}
.red-topbordered{
  border-top-color: #f44336;
}
.screenCentered{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.editableInput {
  color: #2196f3;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<i class="fa fa-clock-o editableInput"></i>
```

Comment: Besides your answer is the solution to my problem, I still cannot detect the typo... can you point me out where is the exact error/typo? please sir.

Comment: @LuisArancibia See the updated answer above....I have attached a image.

Comment: I consider my self as a google search expert xD but when I encounter this error I have noting more to do but to post on stackoverflow.. you are awesome.. thank you very much.

Comment: @LuisArancibia Glad it helped you..!